# Django annotate returning duplicate entries

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-annotate

I'm annotating a queryset like so:

```py
class ItemQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def annotate_subitem_stats(self):
        return self.annotate(
            count_subitems=Count('subitems'),
            has_sent_subitems=Case(
                When(subitems__status=Status.sent, then=Value(True)),
                default=Value(False)
            ),
        )
```

In this example, `SubItem` is a model with a foreign key to `Item`.

A strange behaviour happens when I run this code. Suppose we have 1 `Item` and 2 `SubItem`s linked to it. One subitem has status sent and the other doesn't. When I run annotate on the queryset, the queryset returns the item twice, one with `has_sent_subitems` set to `True` and the other set to `False`. The other strange thing is that, one duplicate has `count_subitems == 1`, and the other has `count_subitems == 1`, as if the queryset has split item into two rows, one where `status == 'sent'` and the other where `status != 'sent'`.

This is basically what the annotated queryset looks like:

```py
[
    {
        'name': 'Item Name',
        'count_subitems': 1,
        'has_sent_subitem': False
    },
    {
        'name': 'Item Name',
        'count_subitems': 1,
        'has_sent_subitem': True
    }
]
```

This is what the database looks like, using pseudocode:

```
item = Item()
SubItem(item=item, status=draft)
SubItem(item=item, status=sent)
```

I'm pretty sure this has to do with line `When(subitems__status=Status.sent, then=Value(True)),`. Is there any way I can make that line check if only 1 item has status sent, and then set the annotation to true and move on?

P.S. Using `.distinct()` didn't work. I can't use `.distinct(field)`, because `annotate() + distinct(fields) is not implemented.`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can instead use [**`Exists`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/expressions/#exists-subqueries) subquery for this, to avoid the join caused by `subitems__status`, so:

```py
from django.db.models import Exists, OuterRef


class ItemQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def annotate_subitem_stats(self):
        return self.annotate(
            count_subitems=Count('subitems'),
            has_sent_subitems=Exists(
                SubItem.objects.filter(item=OuterRef('pk'), status=Status.sent)
            ),
        )
```

Comment: I wonder, would this trigger a query per item in the queryset because of the `SubItem.objects.filter` call?

Comment: No it shouldn't, as a subquery is still part of a "main" query

Answer (score 0):

For some extra context: I think this is a known and documented limitation (though the docs are easy to miss). The [docs on aggreation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/db/aggregation/#combining-multiple-aggregations) have this section (copied from Django 4.2 docs):

> #### Combining multiple aggregations
>
> Combining multiple aggregations with annotate() will yield the wrong results because joins are used instead of subqueries:
>
> ```
> >>> book = Book.objects.first()
> >>> book.authors.count()
> 2
> >>> book.store_set.count()
> 3
> >>> q = Book.objects.annotate(Count('authors'), Count('store'))
> >>> q[0].authors__count
> 6
> >>> q[0].store__count
> 6
> ```
>
> For most aggregates, there is no way to avoid this problem, however, the Count aggregate has a distinct parameter that may help:
>
> ```
> >>> q = Book.objects.annotate(Count('authors', distinct=True), Count('store', distinct=True))
> >>> q[0].authors__count
> 2
> >>> q[0].store__count
> 3
> ```

Another way to circumvent the limitation is to put the aggregate in a subquery. I [previously explained](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/10060#comment:71) how to use the django-sql-utils package for this:

> For anyone else running into this, a reasonable workaround seems to be to use subqueries for aggregating annotations. This is a bit verbose/hacky in Django currently, as shown by the multitude of approaches in the stackoverflow link from [Antoine's comment](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/10060#comment:69). However, I've successfully used the [django-sql-utils package](https://github.com/martsberger/django-sql-utils) for this just now. That sounds a bit bulky, but it just has two utilities, one of which is a SubqueryAggregate class (with derived SubqueryCount, SubquerySum, etc.) that make converting a regular joining aggregate into a subquery aggregate easy and concise, without changing the structure much.
>
> For example taking the example from [comment 66](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/10060#comment:66) and converting the second annotation to a subquery with django-sql-utils, you'd get:
>
> ```
> Branch.objects.annotate(
>     total=Sum('center__client__loan__amount'),
>     repaid=SubquerySum('center__client__loan__payment_schedule__payments__principal'),
> )
> ```

There is also a [bug report tracking this limitation](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/10060).